# Is SEO effected by having a forward slash for the homepage?

Tags: seo

Im refactoring how URLs work on my site. Is there an SEO difference when you have a forward slash or not for the homepage?

Eg

```
website.com?xxx
```

Vs

```
website.com/?xxx
```

Comment: I can't speak to the slash, but if your query string changes, understand that each unique querystring represents a different page to Google and that will likely impact your SEO.  See https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/68304/will-removing-unused-query-string-parameters-negatively-affect-seo/68309#68309

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking if there is a difference in how google treats urls with forward slashes vs. without then no, there isn't much of a difference. You just have to make sure that you always reference a single, "canonical" version of the URL.

Comment: This answer is half right, there is no difference.  However, because the URLs are equivalent, and you do not need to be careful to use just one form.  On the protocol level, there is no way to request the home page without the slash.